# .net calling post request with ssl

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, avalonia

I have this simple request to XTB broker demo account according to the documentation http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/

```
public static async Task Login()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    using StringContent jsonContent = new(
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
        {
            command = "login",
            arguments = new
            {
                userId = "XXXX",
                password = "XXXX",
            }
        }),
        Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json");
    var uri = new Uri("https://xapi.xtb.com:5124");

    using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(
        uri,
        jsonContent);

    var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"{jsonResponse}\n");
}
```

But I am always getting error:

> "IOException: The response ended prematurely."

What I found on the internet is that I need to use ssl connection for request to work, but I am not sure how to implement it inside this avalonia .net project. Is there any way way how can I make ssl request?

Comment: Probably the problem is from somewhere else. Why do you think the problem is ssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/

> Introduction
> ...
> The connection is performed by clean socket connection. For real trading SSL connection will be used.

So that means that You cannot use HTTP request, seems that raw socket + SSL stream need to be used.
I created code snipped to give idea how probably it should work:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace program
{
    class Program
    {
        public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            // this need to be validated correctly, need to find somewhere how to validate it
            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPHostEntry hostEntry;
            string host = "xapi.xtb.com";
            int demoPort = 5124;

            hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);

            //you might get more than one ip for a hostname since 
            //DNS supports more than one record
            if (hostEntry.AddressList.Length < 1) throw new Exception($"cannot resolve host name '{host}'");

            // somehow need to select IP
            var ip = hostEntry.AddressList[1];
            string server = ip.ToString();

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, demoPort);

            using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null))
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);

                var jsonToSend = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
                {
                    command = "login",
                    arguments = new
                    {
                        userId = "XXXX",
                        password = "XXXX",
                    }
                });

                // send/receive data using SslStream
                byte[] toSendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonToSend);
                byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[1024];

                sslStream.Write(toSendBytes);
                int receivedCount = sslStream.Read(receivedBytes);

                string receivedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, receivedCount);

                Console.WriteLine("Received: ");
                Console.WriteLine(receivedString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get following output:

```
Received:
{"status":false,"errorCode":"EX000","errorDescr":"Invalid parameters"}
```

Regards
NeuroXiq